# Integrating Font Awesome Pro (zip distribution) with Angular

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

I want to integrate Font Awesome Pro 6, of which our company bought a license, into our Angular project(s).

My boss gave me the zip distribution (not the NPM private token, which is subject to renewal), and I would like to upgrade [@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome) to use the pro version.

So far, we have been using the free version of FA along with `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons`. In particular, this library declares Typescript symbols used during transpilation.

Before I had (package.json)

```json
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
```

Question: given the zip file of FA Pro 6 which consists of the following

[image: Zip file]

How do I integrate the fonts into Angular projects?

**What I have tried so far**

I have tried to unzip the FA 6 Pro directory into `src/font-awesome-pro`, and delete the 4 last packages (listed above) from `package.json`.

I also expected to amend `angular.json` adding the scss and js manually

```json
            "scripts": [
              ...
              "./src/font-awesome-pro/js/fontawesome.js",
              ...
            ]
```

```json
            "styles": [
              ...
              "./src/font-awesome-pro/scss/fontawesome.scss",
              "./src/styles.scss"
```

But my application won't compile

```
Error: src/app/shared/shared-components/spinner-block/spinner-block.component.ts:5:41 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons' or its corresponding type declarations.

5 import {faSpinner, IconDefinition} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Also

```
export class AmlcFontAwesomeModule {
  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary, faConfig: FaConfig) {
    // Add an icon to the library for convenient access in other components
    library.addIconPacks(far, fas, fab);
    library.addIcons(fa.faPencilAlt, fa.faRecycle, fa.faTrash, fa.faUser, fa.faLock, fa.faHome);
    faConfig.fixedWidth = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the downloadable assets from the website will work with the `angular-fontawesome` library. They are designed to be used in the classic HTML way.

First I would try to convince your boss to give you the token. I don't think it actually changes unless somebody clicks Regenerate button on the website. If not possible, I think you have two options:

1. You should be able to download/install the icon packages and `fontawesome-svg-core` from `npm.fontawesome.com` and commit them to the repository instead of installing them every time. You will need the token for that, but the app won't break if the token is regenerated in the future.
2. Switch from `angular-fontawesome` to the vanilla Font Awesome distribution. That's not the recommended way, but it should work with `<i>` tags being replaced by the vanilla Font Awesome JS code you have in the archive you've got.

Also linking [this issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/issues/264) as it had similar discussion.

Comment: I'll open a further question: how to push FontAwesome npm package from fortawesome.com npm registry to private Azure DevOps npm repository?

Comment: Since I eventually need the token, I would prefer to transfer the entire package to our private npm

Comment: Not an expert in this, but I assume you can download/get from the npm cache the relevant `.tgz` files and [`npm publish package.tgz`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-publish) each of them to the Azure DevOps npm repository.